# What is the best way to handle large recursive queries in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, recursive-query

Using PHP & Mysql-

I have a list of 120,000 employees. Each has a supervisor field with the supervisor employee number.

I am looking to build something that shows the employees in a tree like format. Given that if you click on anyone that you have an option to download all of the employees (with their info) that are under them.

So two questions - should I write my script to handle the query (which I have but is SLOW) or should create some sort of helper table/view?  I am looking for best practice behind this.

Also I am sure this has been done a million times.  Is there a good class that handles organization hierarchy?

Comment: What is the query you are currently using?

Comment: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: @Barmar that is a great article.  Thank you for the link.

Comment: What I have currently written uses the adjacency model.  I can see that the nested set would probably be much faster.  Is that true?  If so then how do I go from parent (supervisor id) - child (empl id) to nested set?  Building the nested set is really beyond what I have done in mysql.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way of doing this is to use one table to store all of the employees, with a primary key field for the `employee_id`, and a field for `supervisor_id` which is a 'self join' - meaning that the value in this field points back to the employee id of this employee's supervisor.  As far as displaying the employee tree - for relatively small trees, the entire tree structure can be sent to the client's browser when the page is created, and tree nodes can be displayed as the nodes are clicked from the stored data.  But, for larger trees, it is better to fetch the data as needed, i.e. when the nodes are clicked.  If you have 120,000 employees, then you might want to use the later approach.

Comment: It is currently set up like that.  I can easily get the immediate subordinates but if I have a VP there might be 6 levels below and I at least need the option to print everything that is there.